# AWS Java SDK 2.0 S3 presigned URL public object access

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

Creating presigned url for file upload in itself is working fine.
But uploading the file through the generated URL by default makes it private and hence cannot be accessed through it's URL

I have to manually go to the console and make the file public to be accessible from it's URL

Here is my code

```java
String bucketName = "<bucket-name>";
String keyName = "<file-name>";

S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder().region(Region.AP_SOUTH_1).build();

PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .key(keyName)
        .build();

PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
        .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
        .putObjectRequest(objectRequest)
        .build();

PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest = presigner.presignPutObject(presignRequest);

System.out.println("Pre-signed URL to upload a file to: " +
        presignedRequest.url());
System.out.println("Which HTTP method needs to be used when uploading a file: " +
        presignedRequest.httpRequest().method());   

presigner.close();
```

In NodeJs we specify that we want the file to be publicly accessible so I found it's java sdk equivalent like this

```java
PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .key(keyName)
        .acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)
        .build();
```

But when uploading through the URL thus generated, I'm getting a singature mismatch error

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not the correct way to make the file publicly accessible? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: in your code you provide public access  `.acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)` so if you want your images only access via signed url put ACL `PRIVATE`

Comment: As I metioned, by defult the files are private. I want to make them public but adding `.acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)` didn't help

Comment: you want to give public access or not? with signed url everyone can check file untill url valid. and after provide ACL PUBLIC READ no need to use sign url.

Comment: I am not using signed url for accessing files. I am using signed urls for uploading files. And I want to make those uploaded files public but using `.acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)`  was not working

Answer (score 2):

I posted the same question on AWS's github for java-sdk and found the solution.

Adding `.acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)` in `PutObjectRequest.builder()` will add `x-amz-acl` in the header as opposed to the query where it is needed

Here's how to add it in the query

```java
AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration override = AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration.builder()
        .putRawQueryParameter("x-amz-acl", "private")
        .build();

PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .key(keyName)
        .overrideConfiguration(override)
        .build();
```

The solution works perfectly. Thought it might help someone else as well

For more info, see [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2053)

Comment: Working perfectly fine!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
new PutObjectRequest("xxx", "xxx, fis, metadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```